# sorting by date value isn't working correctly

Tags: php

Im trying to sort my table by a date but i've entered it as a string. When it sorts by the date column it only sorts by the first part of the date **01**/01/2016. How do i get the php code to look at the whole string and sort by that?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php $usertype=0; ?>
 <?php require('check_if_logged_in.php'); ?>

 <?php
 require_once 'header.php';
 require_once('my_connect.php');


 $my_query="select * from loans order by date_return ASC";
 $result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
 ?>

 <html>
 <h2 align="center">All Existing Loans</h2>
 <body>
 <p align="center">Here are all the loans that have been entered on the Loan System</p>
 <p align="center"><font color="blue"><i> * Blue - Active</i></font></p>
 <p align="center"><font color="red"><i> * Red - Overdue</i></font></p>
 <p align="center"><font color="green"><i> * Green - Completed</i></font>     </p>
 </body>
 </html>
 <table border=1 cellpadding=10>
 <tr><th>Loan ID<th>Product<th>User<th>Expected Return Date?<th>Returned? <th>Edit?

<?php


//$dbdate = date('Y-m-d', $date_return);

while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

$today = date('d-m-Y'); 
$loanid         = $myrow["loanid"];
$product        = $myrow["product"];
$user           = $myrow["user"];
$dbdate         = date('d-m-Y',$myrow["date_return"]);
$date_return    = $myrow["date_return"];
$returned       = $myrow["returned"];

$table = '<tr>';
$table.= '<td>'.$loanid.'</td>';
$table.= '<td>'.$product.'</td>';
$table.= '<td>'.$user.'</td>';
if ($returned == 'Yes'){ 
    $table.= '<td><div style="color: green;">'.$date_return.'</div>';
}else if ($date_return <= $today){
    $table.= '<td><b><div style="color: red;">'.$date_return.'</div></b>';
} else {
    $table.= '<td><div style="color: blue;">'.$date_return.'</div>';
} //end if

$table.= '<td>'.$returned.'</td>';;
$table.= "<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit    This Loan?')\" href=editloaninfo.php?loanid=".$loanid."><img src=\"edit.png\">  </td>";

echo $table;



/*echo "
<tr>
<td>$loanid</td>
<td>$product</td>
<td>$user</td>
<td>$date_return</td>
<td>$returned</td>
<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This Loan?')\" href=editloaninfo.php?loanid=$loanid><img src=\"edit.png\">";*/

endwhile;

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With luck, your date formats are all the same, so you can try this instead:

```
 $my_query="select * from loans order by STR_TO_DATE(date_return, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC";
```

Comment: only other thing thats troubling me with the date format is. with my IF statement in my while loop. It seems to be looking at the date in american format month/date/year. Can you notice if i have any reason the this happening?

Comment: If your dates are in a different format, change the order within the STR_TO_DATE. %m is month, %d is date, %Y is 4 digit year. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html has all of the placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

change the data type of date_return to date but before that convert all string to date form

Comment: Giving an explicit code example might be more helpful